# Dynamically referencing a class (Java)

Tags: java, oop

I have a HashMap using classes as keys and values that links a class (key) with another class that takes an instance of the key class as the only argument for its constructor.

My code looks like this:

```
HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>> links = //Instantiation
//Adding some things to the map
Object object = //The instance I'll use to build some other thing
Class<?> ValueClass = this.links.get(object.getClass());
    try {
        return new ValueClass(object);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) { //Not in the HashMap
        //Some exception handling
    }
```

I don't know much about Java and good coding practices, so besides wanting to know how to do this correctly, I'd like to know if doing this has any important implications and if there's a better way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: What are you really trying to do, here? This is a pretty unusual pattern to see in Java (especially for someone who's new to Java), and it almost feels like and AbstractFactory.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I think he wants to create an instance of a value stored in the map, and whatever key was used to get that value, create an instance of it and pass it to the value instance that was created

Comment: @DavidEhrmann The context is the following: I want to send some JSON objects through a socket, but I don't want the exact same object in JSON format; I want a 'reduced' version of it. The keys are the classes that can get reduced, the values are the reduced versions of them. The value classes take an instance of their corresponding 'bloated' class as the only parameter for their constructor.

Comment: @Laura So all reduced versions of a Foo (if Foo is reducible) will be identical?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Only a few instances of Foo will have an identical 'reduced' version. For example, let Foo have a, b and c as instance variables and make the reduced version only keep a: only the instances that have the same value in a will have an identical reduced version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should create the object according to your description

```
Constructor<?> constr = ValueClass.getConstructor( object.getClass() );
Object newObj = constr.newInstance(object);
```

All sorts of exceptions can be raised by this - see the javadoc.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved to take into account that (1) there's no need for `<?>` (2) variables are written in camelCase and (3) `const` is a reserved word.

Comment: @abl Ah, the unused reserved keyword. But I stick with OP's variable name, and I really don't know anything about the range of classes to be constructed.